# Vector-parametric description of the tangent plane to a function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The vector-parametric description of the tangent plane to the graph of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ at a point $(a, b, f(a, b))$ is the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a\\
b\\
f(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix} + \lambda
\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
f_x(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix} + \mu
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
f_y(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix},$$

where $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$. So every vector on the plane is a linear combination of the two direction vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
f_x(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
f_y(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix}$. Regarding the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 
a\\
b\\
f(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix}$, what are the two scalars necessary to make $f(a, b)$ a linear combination of $f_x(a, b)$ and $f_y(a, b)$, i.e. what are the two scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $f(a, b) = \alpha f_x(a, b) + \beta f_y(a, b)$?

Comment: The point $(a,b,f(a,b))$ is not considered a vector in the tangent plane. The tangent plane is a plane affixed to the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$ just like the standard $x$-$y$ plane can be considered a plane affixed to the origin, $(0,0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, every vector on the plane is a linear combination of the two direction vectors *plus* the vector

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
a\\
b\\
f(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is necessary for the plane to touch the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$.

In other words, the plane parallel to the tangent plane and passing through the origin is given by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
 \lambda
\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
f_x(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix} + \mu
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
f_y(a, b)\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is a [linear subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) and the first vector can be viewed as a translation of this plane from the origin to the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$ which is an [affine subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space).

Comment: So $\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ f(a, b)\\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ f_x(a, b)\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ f_y(a, b)\\ \end{bmatrix}$ are linearly independent, right?

Comment: @RiccardoIorio Not necessarly, this is not a requirement. Without the first vector, that is with the first vector coinciding with the origin, the plane passes  through the origin. The first vector is like a (fixed) translationof the origin to the point $(a,b,f(a,b,))$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you!